# JavaFX - How to periodically read xml file and update TableView

Tags: xml, dom, javafx, tableview

The problem I am facing is that I want my TableView to refresh when the XML file has been updated. TableView updates immediately when data has been modified, and when the user exits and reopens the application, the new data is there as it should be. But I want this update to be "automatic" so that if one of 2 users makes a change, the other users' running application will reflect that change automatically as well.

I would like to periodically read in the XML file but I'm having no luck. I am using DOM to read the file. I have yet to look at ScheduledService but it seems like a potential solution. 
I also added a "refresh data" button, to where it calls the class of where I read in my XML file but that didn't work either. Any hints?

Comment: The Java [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) will help here. Essentially, it fires an event whenever a watched file is modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) API to keep an eye on a folder. This can trigger an event any time a file is add, deleted, or modified.

Here is a quick MCVE to demonstrate. We will only watch for modifications to existing files in this example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Launch the watcher in a background thread
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                setupWatcher();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public static void setupWatcher() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Listening for changes to DATA.XML");

        // Set the directory we want to watch for changes
        Path dir = Paths.get("your/path");

        // Create the WatchService
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        // Only watch for modifications (ignore new or deleted files)
        dir.register(watchService, ENTRY_MODIFY);

        // The WatchKey will collect any events from the WatchService. We want this to run indefinitely so we wrap in
        // an infinite loop
        while (true) {
            // Gets the latest event
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

            // When a change is found, let's find out what kind and act appropriately
            if (watchKey != null) {

                // For each event triggered
                watchKey.pollEvents().forEach(watchEvent -> {

                    // Get the filename of the file that was modified
                    String filename = watchEvent.context().toString();

                    // If it is the file we care about, do something
                    if (filename.equalsIgnoreCase("DATA.XML")) {

                        // Do your update of the TableView here
                        System.out.println("DATA.XML has been changed!");
                    }

                });

                // After the event was processed, reset the watchKey
                watchKey.reset();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Additional information can be found in the JavaDocs or [this tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-8-watchservice-api-tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you for the response! However I'm getting an error of  `java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: U:\test.xml`. I don't exactly know what this means other than it means that the file is not a directory. I thought I just had to put my path there?

Comment: Make sure you don't include the filename in your path.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I just got it. I just put `U:\\` and now when I made a change, the WatchService printed out "TEST.XML has been changed!" on both of my local running applications which is great but unfortunately, the other application didn't have it's tableview updated...  I'm trying to think what I could do. The file has a listener and is working, so I still need to parse the xml file and retrieve the change then right?

Comment: Right, that is still all on you to implement.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the Java WatchService to be notified when the content of your file changes. See [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

Here is also a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice) showing how to use it.